# Schedule X Classes In N Classrooms

Tags: scheduling, partitions, colorings, intervals

I would really appreciate any thought on this, or under which category does this problem fall (Interval scheduling, Interval partitioning,...)
I am really out of thoughts

I have X number of classes each with starting, and finishing time, and N number of free classrooms.
And I want to find the maximum number of non-conflicting classes that can be scheduled in those N classrooms.

What I've tries so far :

## - First algorithm:

- Sort Classes in ascending order according to the finishing time of each class.
- Starting with the minimal finishing time, pick all the intervals that don't conflict with it and save it in a subset.
- Repeat the first two steps on the very next interval that conflicts with the one we were working on before.

### Why wrong?

Ex: we have 4 classes (1,4) (2,6) (6,7) (4,8) and we want to find the maximum number of non-conflicting ones that can be fit in 2 classes.

- Starting the algorithm on (1,4) will give me subset {(1,4)(6,7)} that can be fit in the first classroom, and in the second classroom i need to put either (2,6) or (4,8) but not both since they conflict, so in total 3 of those classes can be fit in 2 classrooms using this approach.
- However in real life you can put {(1,4),(4,8)} in a room and {(2,6),(6,7)} in the other, so all of the classes can be held in the 2 rooms.

## - Second algorithm

- Sort Classes in ascending order according to the starting time of each class.
- Starting with the minimal starting time, pick all the intervals that don't conflict with it and save it in a subset.
- Repeat the first two steps on the very next interval that conflicts with the one we were working on before.

### Why wrong?

Ex: we have 4 classes (1,2) (2,1000) (6,7) (7,8) and we want to find the maximum number of non-conflicting ones that can be fit in **1** class.

- Starting the algorithm on (1,2) will give me subset {(1,2)(2,1000)} that can be fit in the first classroom, and that's it, so in total 2 of those classes can be fit in a classroom using this approach.
- However in real life you can put {(1,2),(6,7),(7,8)} in a room and, so 3 of the classes can be held in a room.

Comment: For N=1, this problem is the interval scheduling problem and the two algorithms you described are optimal for it.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal number of rooms needed can be computed by considering the classes in order of finish times, and if a class can't be fit into any one of the rooms in use, create a new room for it. See e.g. Erickson, ["Algorithms"](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms), section 4.2.

This is the problem of asking if an [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph) can be colored with $N$ colors (the rooms). Perhaps digging into [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) nets some algorithm(s). It isn't a problem for which I've seen a simple algorithm. Determining if a general graph is $N$ colorable is NP-complete (i.e., no much better solution expected than just trying all possibilities) if $N \ge 3$, perhaps being an interval graph is enough of a restriction to make it tractable...

Comment: Coloring interval graphs is in P by sorting the intervals by finish time and coloring them greedily. This gives us an optimal N such that ALL classes can be scheduled. However the question is how many vertices one can color with a given number of colors. Maybe the algorithm can be adapted to that.